# Очистить содержимое ячеек таблицы определенного цвета

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть google таблица, некоторые ячейки имеют заливку, нужно очистить содержимое ячеек определенного цвета. 
В MS Excel это было реализовано так:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
If cell.Interior.color = 13391121 Then cell.ClearContents
```

Как сделать аналогичную функцию в google app script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть [большой топик](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5809954) на тему очистки диапазонов.

Вам нужно воспользоваться [примером из сниппетов](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/31e74284e5481b6f57f00d62cfc21fe1f024ee2a/snippets/spreadsheet_reset-sheets/reset-sheets.js).

В общем случае, скрипт выглядит так

```
/**
 * Clear specifing sheets by color
 */
function userActionResetMultipleSheetsByColor() {
  var fColor = '#fa7d00';
  var sheetNames = [
    // { name: 'Sheet1' },
    { name: 'Reset by color (click the image)' },
  ];
  sheetNames.forEach(function(sn) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sn.name);
    if (sheet) {
      var rangesAddressesList = sheet
        .getDataRange()
        .getFontColors()
        .reduce(function(p, row, i) {
          var colors = row.reduce(function(p2, color, j) {
            if (color === fColor)
              p2.push(Utilities.formatString('R%sC%s', i + 1, j + 1));
            return p2;
          }, []);
          if (colors.length) p = p.concat(colors);
          return p;
        }, []);
      if (rangesAddressesList.length)
        resetByRangesList_(sheet, rangesAddressesList);
    }
  });
}
```

Я вам настоятельно не рекомендую повторять что-то из VBA, т.к. это совершенно разные языки.

Функция `userActionResetMultipleSheetsByColor` в данном примере вызывается пользователем из меню или по нажатию на картинку.

Где `resetByRangesList_`

```
/**
 * Clear the sheet by the range list
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet The sheet
 * @param {Array.<string>} rangesAddressesList The list of ranges to return, as specified in A1 notation or R1C1 notation.
 */
function resetByRangesList_(sheet, rangesAddressesList) {
  sheet.getRangeList(rangesAddressesList).clearContent();
}
```